# ASP.NET MVC public static list not same after POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, static, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to MVC and i have problem i can't understand. Below code is what i want to attain:

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace testapplication.Models {
    public class testModel {

        public class SystemUser {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }

        public static List<SystemUser> list1;
        public static void CreateList1() {
            list1 = new List<SystemUser>();
        }

        public static void FillList1() {
            SystemUser firstUser = new SystemUser();
            firstUser.Name = "name";
            firstUser.Email = "email@address.com";
            list1.Add(firstUser);
        }

        public static List<SystemUser> list2 = new List<SystemUser>();    
        public static void FillList2() { 
            SystemUser firstUser = new SystemUser();
            firstUser.Name = "name";
            firstUser.Email = "email@address.com";
            list2.Add(firstUser);
        }

        public static string list3 = "test";
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using testapplication.Models;

namespace testapplication.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {

        public ActionResult Index() {
            testModel.CreateList1();
            testModel.FillList1();
            testModel.FillList2();
            var var1 = testModel.list1;
            var var2 = testModel.list2;
            var var3 = testModel.list3;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string test) {
            var var1 = testModel.list1;
            var var2 = testModel.list2;
            var var3 = testModel.list3;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
}
```

Before POST method list1,list2 and list3 are ok but right after Post list1 is null, list2 is empty (instance is created) and list3 is ok. Why is that? I want to have same value before and after POST.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: you are right. sorry about it

Comment: It's not directly clear what happens, looks like they should be filled. But one general rule in MVC (and ASP.NET in general) is to avoid `static` . So do you really want to pursue this?

Comment: I used to not use any static values or methods but i'm in need to have it like it is above. Is there any way to fix it? I've heared that sometimes people use "lock" to fix similar problems but i have no idea if it is possible to do so in POST. If there is no way i can have it in this way, I will use those methods one more time after POST without any static.

Comment: Try to make a small(er) but complete program. Your current code has syntax errors and I think the relevant parts are missing.

Comment: If I refresh page before POST all is working perfectly. Ok i will try and yes there are syntax errors because i wanted to show only idea of what is going on.

Comment: I have created empty MVC solution and add to it only 3 files with code above (edited to work). Still the same problem.

Comment: OK, +1 for fixing the question. But now: status no-repro. It works fine on my PC. VS2010, MVC3, Dev server.

Comment: It was created and debugged in Visual Studio 2012 Express(.Net Framework 4.5, IIS Express). I have tried it in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express(.Net Framework 3.5) and it is working. There must be reason why it's not working in VS 2012. Maybe something about IIS settings?

Comment: I'll try it with 2012 later today. Could be IIS express too (you can turn that off).

Comment: I have changed from IIS Express to Development Server and when i'm starting to debbug i'm getting information that "Server is too busy". After refresh all is working fine.

Comment: This seems like a bad way to use static properties.  There are many better ways.

Comment: Do not use static fields in an ASP.NET application of any kind. Such fields are shared across _all_ users of the application.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not using a strongly-typed view neither static variables. So, your lists are "valid" only in your [HttpGet] Action.

You could try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using testapplication.Models;

namespace testapplication.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        private static testapplication.Models.testModel testModel;

        public ActionResult Index() {
            testModel.CreateList1();
            testModel.FillList1();
            testModel.FillList2();
            var var1 = testModel.list1;
            var var2 = testModel.list2;
            var var3 = testModel.list3;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string test) {                
            var var1 = testModel.list1;
            var var2 = testModel.list2;
            var var3 = testModel.list3;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```